# setting a default virtual host in WHM Manager

Tags: apache, centos, virtualhost, whm

I am hosting a bunch of websites with WHM Manager on a CentOS server. One of my websites (examplesiteone.com) allows for user accounts to be created as subdomains (username.examplesiteone.com). With this feature I then have the option for users to add an A Record to point their own url (theircompanyname.com) to my server's IP, then my renderer does a lookup to find the appropriate subdomain to serve the pages accordingly.

In order for this to work I had my server setup so that examplesiteone.com was the default domain name to be resolved on my server; I achieved this by listing it as the first site within my vhost.conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d/

I have now needed to switch the site over to a new server that is using WHM Manager and I can't seem to find any way to set a default website for unknown hostnames.